# Intersect Two Lists c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

Hello I have these two Lists

```
List<string> list1 = {"404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29190_806.jpg|Name1", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29197_806.jpg|Name2", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29210_868.jpg|Name3"}
List<string> list2 = {"404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29190_806.jpg","404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29197_806.jpg"}
```

I want to intersect the values of list1 separating by **'|'** character, with the list2 values, but I want to return the full string of list1 and not only the first part separated by '|' character.

This is the result i want:

```
var finalList = {"404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29190_806.jpg|Name1", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29197_806.jpg|Name2"}
```

I dont know if its possible with the instersect function or there is another approach I can use. I've tried using **Contains** function in a predicate but it takes to much time to find the matches.

I'm using large lists with 2000 elements approx.

Thanks!

Comment: @tnw OP: "*I've tried using Contains function in a predicate but it takes to much time to find the matches.*"

Comment: @p.s.w.g I know, I read it too but there isn't any effort *shown*, I.E. no code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, gives the expected results in LinqPad, using your example:

```
var intersection =
    list1.Join(
        list2,
        l1 => l1.Split('|')[0], //Selector for items from the inner list splits on '|'
        l2 => l2,               //Select the current item
        (l1, l2) => l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile `list2` into a `HashSet<string>` to allow fast lookups. Then, use a simple `Where` filter to perform lookups of substrings from `list1` against this set.

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29190_806.jpg|Name1", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29197_806.jpg|Name2", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29210_868.jpg|Name3" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29190_806.jpg", "404a49ad-d80f-4ef7-99ab-0996de3b70d4_29197_806.jpg" };

var list2HashSet = new HashSet<string>(list2);
var finalList = list1.Where(s => list2HashSet.Contains(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('|')))).ToList();
```

Note that `s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('|'))` is semantically equivalent to `s.Split('|')[0]` (assuming that all your strings contain `|`), but avoids the overhead of allocating another string instance for the text behind the `|`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `where` to iterate over the list. Use the `Split` method to get the first part you are interested in, and then check to see if `list2` contains that string.  Finally call `ToList` to convert the result to a list.

```
var finalList = list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x.Split(new []{'|'})[0})).ToList();
```

Comment: This will re-iterate `list2.Contains(x.Split(new []{'|'})[0})` 2,000 times based on the question been asked. `Where` with a nested `Contains` can often cause performance problems.

Comment: @DaveShaw - that makes sense.  Shall I keep this answer here as example of what *not* to do?

Comment: I was using something like this but it cause perfomance problems, thanks Dave